# Ruby Unicorn - Thread Exception

Tags: ruby, exception, cassandra, sinatra, unicorn

I have a Sinatra Application which has connections to a Cassandra Cluster and to a Postgres. For the Cassandra Connection I'm using the datastax cassandra-driver. As App Server I'm using unicorn. 
This is how I open my connection:

```
configure do
    enable :logging
     set :show_exceptions, ((ENV['SHOW_EXCEPTIONS'] || 'true') == 'true')
    cluster = Cassandra.cluster(
       username: ENV['CASSANDRA_USERNAME'],
       password: ENV['CASSANDRA_PASSWORD'],
       hosts: ENV['CASSANDRA_HOSTS'].split(',')
)
keyspace = 'YYXXXX'
set :session, cluster.connect(keyspace)
```

Local Everything works (with rackup as dev server), on production i get fatal - no Live threads left. Deadlock? 
Do you have a idea whats wrong with my config?

Below you find my stacktrace:

```
172.31.4.18, 35.156.240.164 - - [23/Jan/2017:20:23:41 +0000] "GET /    
HTTP/1.0" 200 1744 0.0071
46.105.28.183 - - [23/Jan/2017:20:23:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 1744 0.0066
2017-01-23 20:23:46 - fatal - No live threads left. Deadlock?:
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:111:in `sleep'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:111:in `wait'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:111:in `wait'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/cassandra-driver-3.1.0/lib/cassandra/future.rb:616:in `block in get'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/cassandra-driver-3.1.0/lib/cassandra/future.rb:607:in `get'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/cassandra-driver-3.1.0/lib/cassandra/future.rb:396:in `get'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/cassandra-driver-3.1.0/lib/cassandra/session.rb:123:in `execute'
/code/voucher_cloud.rb:72:in `block in <class:VoucherCloud>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1610:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1610:in `block in compile!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:975:in `block (3 levels) in route!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:994:in `route_eval'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:975:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1015:in `block in process_route'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1013:in `catch'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1013:in `process_route'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:973:in `block in route!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:972:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:972:in `route!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1085:in `block in dispatch!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `block in invoke'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `catch'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `invoke'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1082:in `dispatch!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:907:in `block in call!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `block in invoke'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `catch'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `invoke'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:907:in `call!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:895:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:18:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:18:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/frame_options.rb:31:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/logger.rb:15:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:212:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:182:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:2013:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1487:in `block in call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1787:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1487:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/lint.rb:49:in `_call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/lint.rb:37:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/showexceptions.rb:24:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:219:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/chunked.rb:54:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/unicorn-5.2.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:562:in `process_client'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/unicorn-5.2.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:658:in `worker_loop'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/unicorn-5.2.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:508:in `spawn_missing_workers'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/unicorn-5.2.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:132:in `start'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/unicorn-5.2.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/unicorn:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/unicorn:22:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DataStax Ruby driver documentation mentions that deadlock can occur when ["using a framework, server or runtime that forks and you call Client.connect in the parent process"](http://datastax.github.io/ruby-driver/features/#i-get-deadlock-detected-errors).